# Add a counter in react

Tags: reactjs, counter, react-props

I am trying to make a shopping cart and I want to add a counter into the header but I get an error that says "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

This is the code for the header:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
function Toolbar(props){
    const {cart} = props;
    return(
<header>
    <button>
    <span>
        Go To Cart: 
      {cart.length}</span>
        </button>
    </header>
    )

}
export default Toolbar;
```

And this is the code for the products page. It does count in the console log but not on the screen.

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react'
function Products(props) {
    const [cart, setCart]=useState([]);
    const addtoCart=(props)=>{
        console.log('we are in addToCart');
        setCart([...cart,props]);
    };
    return(
        <div >
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <div className="product" key={props.id}>
      <h3>{props.name}</h3>
      <h4>{props.cost}</h4>
      <img src ={props.image} alt="/"/>
      
      <button onClick={()=>addtoCart(props)}>Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
   
  }
  
  export default Products;
```

Comment: Where are you using your ToolBar Component and what data are you passing :)

Comment: @loana: If you could place all your code on codesandbox and share the link with me.... I can fix this issue for you :)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-galois-li9lb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Let me check :)

Comment: So, dear Friend  As I wrote in my answer as well. Yes the issue Is that ToolBar is receiving no Props.  It is like <Toolbar /> ... Let me format the code better... State Data is not being used properly... Will get back to you with a solution pretty soon :)

Comment: This is the formatted code... https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-resolved-jlgby You may need more changes as per your requirement...

Comment: but still when i click on add to cart nothing it's working

Comment: Yes, The reason is State is modified from 1 place. Which should be Parent. And Another reason is Add to cart functionality is wrongly written My friend...

Comment: Shall I fix it for you :) By the way which country are you from and what is the Time right now there !!!

Comment: Yes, please. I am in the uk, it's 8:37 pm here

Comment: I got it... Wait... let me fix it... You need the Cart functionality .. I mean as the user clicks on Add Item... It should be added on the header :) Right?

Comment: Here, In Kashmir it is 2:07am... No problem I will try to fix it :)

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Let me try to fix this. Just a moment mate

Comment: Can you fix it on the one i sent to you please. I mean only if you can

Comment: OK I will try to do it on the one you send. no problem. Have Faith... Just tell me one thing.. Initially there should be no items in the cart. RIght .. So 0

Comment: yes, i didn't make that part yet

Comment: I am fixing Counter problem for you for now :)

Comment: Hi There ! The Basic Cart Functionality is done :)

Comment: have a look https://codesandbox.io/s/serve-humanity-8hm17 ...

Comment: Now There is logic part of when to add an item, and when not to add... I have just kept it simple for now. Again, A user may click on one item more than once... So in your data you need to add amount field as well.... But Basic functionality is covered. And Data flow is smooth as well :)

Comment: Do Vote and Accept if my answer has helped you in any way or form. :) And you get stuck you can always let me know on emmeiwhite@gmail.com. BEST WISHES :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not passing any props to the `ToolBar` Component.

**UPDATE:**  Based on the comments and codesandbox link that you shared indeed this was your problem. No props where being passed to the `ToolBar` component.

**I have modified the code here on CodeSandBox:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/serve-humanity-8hm17

And I would like to point out the fact that If you are passing props to the `ToolBar` Component but the Component is rendered before data was available, in that case also you will get this error.

In this case you can add a check:

```
 <span>
        Go To Cart: 
     {cart.length && cart.length}
 </span>
```

**Note:** To cross-verify whether you are actually receiving any props or not. Do a `console.log(props.cart)` in your `Toolbar` Component just after declaring it.

```
function Toolbar(props){
    console.log(props);
    const {cart} = props;
    return(...)
}
```

This way you will have a better Idea about what is going on with the data and you can better debug your app :)